# When to use NSOperationQueue's mainQueue, when to create a new queue?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

This is the first time I use NSOperation/NSOperationQueue.
I wrote a NSOperation subclass that handles JSON export of a lot of data,  because I want the UI to stay responsive during a longer export.

To which queue do I add my operation:
- the [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] or
- to a new NSOperationQueue, [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]?

And what is the reasoning behing the decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main queue uses the same thread that handles UI operations.  You want long operations sent to a background queue and then anything that displays the operation's results should come back to the main queue.

Comment: When would I add something to the main queue at all?

Comment: You would add something to the main queue if you're processing in a background queue and need to update some UI element.  Progress for a long-running operation is pretty common.